# Which java server to run a jar application?

Tags: java, jar, jenkins

I made a java program which runs unit test on my website.
I need the unit test to keep running during the day while I watch the log.
For this, I search a java platform on which I can run my soft. Openshift will be the best because it's easy to install and maintain.

However I will often modify this soft and if the java project could be built whenever I made a commit it will be the best. That's why I think to Jenkins, but I don't know if it is a good way to run a jar from a jenkins server whereas it is made to do build.

I tried JBoss and tomcat by wrapping my programs into an Enterprise Application Client but I can not run and check the log of the program from a web interface.

Currently my project is a Java Application, using MySQL, hibernate, maven and git.

What would be the best option for you ?

Thanks.

Florian C.

Comment: How would anyone else know what server a webapp you wrote which we've never seen will run best on?

Comment: the log will get printed on the console. What do you mean by web interface?

Comment: @davidbrainerd This is an architectural issue, I would like to run a jar soft on a server, without using a simple JVM installed on a linux distribution, what is the best option ?

Comment: @JackMoore I would like an admin web console which lists my app and if they are running, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is my soluce.

I use Jenkins.
When I push on Jenkins, my project is automatically built and ran using a shell script.
If the build or the run fails Jenkins sends me the command output by mail.
Else, every day, the project is run (using the cron of jenkins) and the console output is sent to me by mail, so I can check the result of my test.